# Javascript html function input button output

Tags: javascript, html, function, input, output

I am struggling with the following task.

got a javascript function:

```
function dec2bin(dec){

    return (dec >>> 0).toString(2);

}
```

my html should look like this:
- one input field for the "dec"-parameter.
- one button "calculate" to start the function dec2bin <-- the parameter must be taken from the input field mentioned above.
- one input(output) field to show the result after a number was entered in the input field and the button was clicked.

i have no idea why it doesnt works, but i guess the problem is located in one or both of the "***" marked lines:

```
***<input type="text" id="input" value="input"/>***
<input type=button id="button1" value="calculate" onclick="dec2bin('input');"/>
<p id = "output"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function dec2bin(dec){

    return (dec >>> 0).toString(2);

}
***document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = dec2bin(document.getElementById("input").innerHTML);***
</script>
```

thanks!

Comment: wrong guess.
its in 1) onclick="dec2bin('input');"  and in 2) return (dec >>> 0).toString(2);
read, and do home works without cheating!! ^_^

Comment: You get the value of an input with `.value`, not `.innerHTML`. And you need to wait until the user enters something, so the code should be in an event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you used [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_bitwise_convert) as a foundation of your code.

The difference here is that you need to **wait for the user to click the button**.

What your code does **right now** is calling `dec2bin('input')` everytime the user clicks the button, but this method only performs a calculation. The line that populates your `output` is the second "***" marked line but it is only performed on page load.

So instead of doing `document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = dec2bin(document.getElementById("input").value);` on page load, you need to **wrap it with a function** and use it when the user clicks on `button1`.

So the two key points are:

### Wrap the line will get the `input` value and populate the `output`

```
function convertUserInput(id) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = dec2bin(document.getElementById(id).value);
}
```

### Use the function as the `onclick` handler

```
<input type=button id="button1" value="calculate" onclick="convertUserInput('input');"/>
```

**Obs:** IMO is better to use `value` instead of `innerHTML` when it comes to `input` elements.

Comment: **IMHO** is better to provide a guidance and a brief explanation that will make easier the learning process instead of throwing hints that may lead to confusion.